# aws-s3 | Is there a server-side filter for aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to get some stats from a large bucket (90TB~) about last modified timestamp and some searches (ad hoc based on some keys/prefix). Based on https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/, there is a cost for list request, so approaches like pagination or even `--query` (seems like it is client-side filter) are not eligible for this problem based on the amount of calls ($0.005 per 1,000 requests) that are going to be required for each filter.

Do we have a server-side filter that we can use with parameters as search criteria and only returning filtered-data?

Comment: There's no server-side filter that I'm aware of with S3. You could use the S3 Inventory report instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an excellent use-case for using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html).

It can provide a daily file containing a list of all objects and their metadata.

Comment: Thanks, John, that was a great solution in terms of costs and time processing. Currently checking with smaller bucket and it worked perfectly as per the requirements.